# ajax 'script' dataType not working?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use this function for infinite scroll:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
(function() {
  var page = 1,
      loading = false;

  function nearBottomOfPage() {
    return $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200;
  }

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if (loading) {
      return;
    }

    if(nearBottomOfPage()) {
      loading = true;
      page++;
      $.ajax({
        url: '/paginate?page=' + page,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function(data) {
          $(".res-list").append(data.responseText);
          $(window).sausage('draw');
          loading = false;
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $(window).sausage();
}());
</script>
```

The problem is it's not appending the data to the unordered list, even though `http://localhost:3000/paginate?format=js&page=2` works perfectly.

If I put console.log beneath the line that says: `if(nearBottomOfPage()) {` it triggers, so i know the function is working fine. Yet if I put the console.log within success:  for the ajax function it never triggers.... and still further, If i run the ajax command through console it returns exactly what I need in the 'responseText', with success code 200... so i have no idea why it would nto be triggering a success message in console log if its successfully returning 200 when i do it manually..

heres the controller

```
  def paginate
    @resources = Resource.order(:created_at).page(params[:page]).per(20)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead of `$.ajax()`?

Comment: this is more a ruby question, but its 400 (Bad Request) because its forming the url like this... http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]?_=1334548636070

Comment: Use a debugger to figure out why the URL is wonky. I don't know where that URL is coming from, but I do know that `'[object Object]'` comes from `toString()`ing an object; for example: `({}).toString()`

Comment: the URL is hardcoded into the script (see above), its just /paginate?page=x. As far as whats on the page, it must be in script format (format.js in respond_to method) and you will see plaintext html for a bunch of list items

Comment: I've tried using load() now too... i can see the response workign perfectly in the console window. headers are 200 OK, the 'preview' shows the exact code i want.... yet it simply doesnt append or load or do anything

Comment: Based on that response, have you tried adding cache: false?

Comment: have tried with **dataType: 'text'** ?

Comment: post that as an answer and ill mark it as correct. final code was this:  $.ajax({
           url: '/paginate?format=js&page=' + page,
           type: 'get',
           dataType: 'text',
           success: function(data) {
             $(".res-list").append(data);
             loading = false;
           }
         });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '/paginate?format=js&page=' + page, 
  type: 'get', 
  dataType: 'text', 
  success: function(data) { 
    $(".res-list").append(data); 
    loading = false; 
  } 
});
```